# Which different widths of code points regarding the print column do exist, supposed an `a` has width of print column `1`?

Tags: perl, unicode, printing, column-width

Which different widths of code points regarding the print column do exist, supposed an `a` (`\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A}`) has width of print column `1`?

Edit:

"print column width" refers to the output to a terminal

Comment: Unless you are using a fixed-width font (in which case all characters have a normalized display width of 1, except Asian double-width characters, for which it's 2), the display width of each character depends on the character's font. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You're looking for an font-glyph analyze code in perl? or what?

Comment: @tripleee: there are also 0-width characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Unicode, characters can be nonspacing (0 columns), narrow (1 column) or wide (2 columns). You can get the number of columns a string would take using the method `columns` from [`GCString`](http://search.cpan.org/~nezumi/Unicode-LineBreak-2012.06/lib/Unicode/GCString.pod), or `mbswidth` from [`Text::CharWidth`](http://search.cpan.org/~kubota/Text-CharWidth-0.04/CharWidth.pm).

Of course, this only works for monospaced output, e.g: output to a terminal.